# Center crop dont work in gridlayoutmaneger Android

Tags: java, android, xml, list, android-recyclerview

I have grid view which is using GridLayoutManager and the RecyclerView
grid has 3 rows which are working fine as you see,[![enter image description here][1]][1]

but for some reason, image views scale type won't work on any of the items and those items you see work fine because the resolution already is square mean 512*512 but if you see the last item that has low resolution it have white space in left and right.

that's my code from a setup list

```
int getori = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (getori == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                gl = new GridLayoutManager(getBaseContext(), 3);
            } else if (getori == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                gl = new GridLayoutManager(getBaseContext(), 6);
            }

            gg.setHasFixedSize(true);
            gg.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
            gg.setLayoutManager(gl);
            gg.setAdapter(startpostsystem);
```

that's my grid adapter code

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Grid_view holder, final int position) {






            holder.im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getfiledop = fall[position].getAbsolutePath();
            Intent is = new Intent(cm,Open_post_item.class);
            is.putExtra("req",12);
            cm.startActivity(is);
```

and this is my grid view items layout code.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="140dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView18"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sunbow100" />
```

I tried to use :
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
or fitxy it make it worse
view bounds won't work either.

if i add more images like 800*400 or ... it will have white space

so where is problem where I do wrong.

Comment: have you try using `android:scaleType="fitXY"` ?

Comment: @Biscuit yes it make it worse and  it broke other images that show well in centercrop

Answer (score 0):

try using android:src in place of app:srcCompat

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView18"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/sunbow100" />
```

Comment: I try that before It has nothing to do with src problam is else where

Comment: Are you using glide or Picasso to set the image on imageview?

Comment: Its android default image view

Comment: Show me the java code of setting the image in that ImageView,
Which must be inside the adapter's(startPostSystem) getView() method.

Comment: It is recyclerview bro it dont have getview() method it has oncreateview which is only code in it is view with infliate

Comment: Then show me the onBindViewHolder() method.
Show me the java code where you are setting the images in the imageview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211433/discussion-between-rahul-samaddar-and-er-reflex).